# Java String Search - Search text of dynamic length on either side of string

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I have a question. I am trying to search for the text on either side of the |.

This is the string which I have added to an array
[No, MDO, 200, AbcN, -, 497218|AU59, 800987619804277, voucher, Customer, 00:00:00, 16.10.2020]

I would like to find these text on either side of the pipe  497218|AU59

Note: The indexes always changes for the array values but the string with the pipe is always available, so the string in question never has the same index which means I cannot search on the entire string but I can find the index of |.

Extracting the values after adding to List does not work for me because indexes always changes:

```
List<String> instanceListSplit = Arrays.asList(iList.split( " "));
```

I have added the entire string to an array because on the screen they are separated by spaces:

```
String[] instanceSplitToArray = (String[]) Arrays.asList(iList.split( " ")).toArray();
```

This might not work for my scenario because I need the text on either side of the pipe | :

```
arrayListmy.add(iList.substring(iList.lastIndexOf("|")));
```

Can someone please tell me how I can get the text on either side of the pipe, 497218|AU59. These text do not have set Lengths either, meaning that the text on the left can have -n amount of characters.

```
List<String> instanceList = Arrays.asList(bulkGridInfo.split( "\n"));

for (String iList : instanceList){
   String[] instanceSplitToArray = (String[]) Arrays.asList(iList.split( " ")).toArray();
                List<String> instanceListSplit = Arrays.asList(iList.split( " "));
                ArrayUtils.reverse(toReverse);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toReverse));
                arrayListmy.add(iList.substring(iList.lastIndexOf("|")).replace("|",""));
            }
```

The arrayListmy value is AU59, which is fine i can find it but I also need the number text to the left of the pipe which can be any length in size. I thought reversing it might be easier to find the text but gets me in the same challenge.

Comment: How is the question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Iterative solution

Trivial iterative solution:

```java
String value = "[No, MDO, 200, AbcN, -, 497218|AU59, 800987619804277, voucher, Customer, 00:00:00, 16.10.2020]";
String[] tokens = value.split("\\[|\\]|,\\s+");
String pipeItem = "";
for (String token : tokens) {
    if (token.contains("|")) {
        pipeItem = token;
        break;
    }
}
String[] pipeTokens = pipeItem.split("\\|");
System.out.println("first token: " + pipeTokens[0]);  // left part
System.out.println("second token: " + pipeTokens[1]); // right part
```

#### Declarative solution

This also could be done with Streams as one liner:

```java
String value = "[No, MDO, 200, AbcN, -, 497218|AU59, 800987619804277, voucher, Customer, 00:00:00, 16.10.2020]";
String [] pipeTokens = Arrays.stream(value.split("\\[|\\]|,\\s+"))
        .filter(item -> item.contains("|"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(item -> item.split("\\|"))
        .get();

System.out.println("first token: " + pipeTokens[0]);  // left part
System.out.println("second token: " + pipeTokens[1]); // right part
```

Comment: If the pipe delimited tuple is the first item in that list, this solution will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Regex to extract the Strings on both sides of the pipe.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "[No, MDO, 200, AbcN, -, 497218|AU59, "
            + "800987619804277, voucher, Customer, 00:00:00, 16.10.2020]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\w+)\\|(\\w+).*");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println("Text before pipe: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Text after pipe: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Text before pipe: 497218
Text after pipe: AU59
```

Comment: Isn't `(\\w+)\\|(\\w+)` safer here? What If the list string is `[|]`, or `[asd, asdad, |,  ]`?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with String based operations

```
 String str = "[No, MDO, 200, AbcN, -, 497218|AU59, 800987619804277, voucher, Customer, 00:00:00, 16.10.2020]";
        String[] strings = str.split("\\|");
        String firstNumber = strings[0].substring(strings[0].lastIndexOf(",") + 2); // we are using 2 because 1 is the comma and second is the white space
        String secondNumber = strings[1].substring(0,strings[1].indexOf(","));

        System.out.println(firstNumber + " " + secondNumber);
```

Comment: I appreciate it, let me attempt this

Comment: If the pipe delimited tuple is at the first item in that list, this solution will fail.

Comment: I appreciate all the responses and help on this question. I have attempted all solutions too.